# Rewriting url SEO friendly, how to reverse back?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

Given that I know how to set the .htaccess...

So my user instead of

```
http://www.pets.com/products.php?id=7
```

will see

```
http://www.pets.com/products/7/
```

But how to manage urls with no id numbers like

```
http://www.pets.com/products/dog-food-purina
```

How can I write a general * rule to do that? Is it possible?
I thought I could write a php script that appends in the htaccess the rules one by one, one for each link, but it seems crazy right?

Something like

```
   #RewriteRule ^dog-food-purina/$  product.php?id=1 [NC,L]  
   #RewriteRule ^dog-food-otherbrand/$  product.php?id=2 [NC,L]  
   ...etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make an additional unique identifier in your database, so that a row of data has both a unique ID (7) and a unique "slug" (dog-food-purina)? That way you can look up rows any way you want by simply forwarding either the slug or the ID to your PHP script and handling it all there.

```
For example: your purina row can be as follows:
row -> id = 1
row -> name = "Purina Dog Food"
row -> description = "This is awesome stuff!"
row -> slug = "dog-food-purina"
row -> quantity = "10lbs"
row -> price = "5"
```

And then do something like this:

```
if (is_string($param) && !empty($param)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE slug = '{$param}'"
} else if (is_numeric($param) && $param > 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = {$param}"
} else return false
```

Hope it helps

Comment: yes that is what I meant: the "slug", so as I understood I need as slug obviously...ok great that confirms my thoughts! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is unnecessary. Why not forward anything after /products/ to products.php, and that script will perform the lookup as necessary? (i.e. it will detect an id, or perform a lookup based on the name)

Comment: right, but also my question is: if i send it to a php script then for each product i should store a keyword like "dog-food-purina" so i can match the url right? i dont see other way...

Comment: Yes, if you want to look up products by name (or by another identifier), you'll need to store them for each product and then do a lookup when someone hits that endpoint. Or, if 'dog-food-purina' isn't unique, you'll need to do a text search.